# Joining two tables on specific attribute using DAX

Tags: excel, join, powerbi, dax

I've got two tables which have the following structure:

In the first table there are users, groups in which the users are members and the domain of the user.

```
username    memberOf    domain 
--------    --------    ------
user1       groupA      ABC   
user1       groupB      ABC       
user1       groupC      ABC   
user2       groupA      DEF       
user2       groupD      DEF
```

In the second table there are groups and the domain of the groups.

```
groupname    domain   
--------     ------   
groupA        DEF       
groupB        GHI      
groupC        ABC       
groupD        GHI
```

Now I want to join my two tables on the groupname i.e. `memberOf = groupname`.

DAX' `NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(<table1>, <table2>)` would join the tables on their common attributes which means that also the domain would be joined.

Is there a way to join the two tables using a specifid column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables by creating a relationship between them, on the columns you choose:

[image: screen capture of relationship between UserTable[memberOf] and GroupTable[groupname]]

Comment: Thanks this worked! But I still wonder if this is the only way to specify the atributes to join on.

Comment: Why do you want another way?